# Differences between SQL Server Hierarchyid and Entity Framework HierarchyId

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, hierarchy

I am seeing different behavior for the [MS SQL Server Datatype `hierarchyid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver15), and the corresponding Entity Framework 6 class `System.Data.Entity.Hierarchy.HierarchyId` (from the assembly `EntityFramework.6.3.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll`).
(I was unable to find the api doc for this type, but the [source code](https://github.com/dotMorten/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/blob/master/src/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/SqlHierarchy/HierarhyId.cs) seems to be identical to [`Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlhierarchyid?view=sql-smo-140.17283.0))

I have a `HierarchyId`, e.g. `childA = '/1/1.1/'`. Now I want to get the next `HierarchyId` on the same level.
So I call `childA.GetAncestor(1).GetDescendant(childA,null)`

Sql server returns `'/1/2/'`, but Entity Framework returns `'/1/1.2/'`.

So when I insert a node into the database via Entity Framework, it gets a different ID as when using stored SQL procedures or triggers, and when I later want to search for a node by its predicted ID, the search may fail.

Is there a way to get the SQL behaviour in EF, without a database roundtrip?

Example SQL Code:

```sql
Declare @ChildA hierarchyid
select @ChildA = '/1/1.1/'
select CAST (@ChildA.GetAncestor(1).GetDescendant(@ChildA,null) as varchar) as ChildB
-- RESULT: ChildB = '/1/2/'
```

Example C# Code:

```cs
var childA = new System.Data.Entity.Hierarchy.HierarchyId("/1/1.1/");
var childB = childA.GetAncestor(1).GetDescendant(childA,null);
Console.WriteLine(childB);
// RESULT: ChildB = "/1/1.2/"
```

Comment: Since logically both results are a descendent of `/1/` that are after `/1/1.1/`, what *problem* is it causing you that they choose different representations of that logical relationship?

Comment: One problem is that a node should get the same predictable ID, whether it is inserted or updated by SQL or by EF; otherwise the ID is not quite that useful. I can work around that by exclusively using only SQL or only EF. But the real problem is that the EF IDs will get rather long and ugly this way :)